# HTML: How to change ordered list item point displays?

Tags: html, css, format, html-lists, display

I have an `<ol>` tag (ordered list) in my `HTML` document.
I would like it to display items in the following format:

```
(i)    Item 1
(ii)   Item 2
(iii)  Item 3
```

Currently I have it working with the following `HTML` code:

```
<ol type="i">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

This gives me the following result:

```
i.    Item 1
ii.   Item 2
iii.  Item 3
```

Is it possible to display my list in the desired way I mentioned at the beginning of this question?

**EDIT:**  *Follow up question which is also part of accepted answer*

How can I get wrapped items (items that are too long for one line) to automatically start new lines on the same tab line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only `CSS3`, you can do it as follows:

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: increment_var;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "(" counter(increment_var, lower-roman) ") ";
    counter-increment: increment_var;
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
li {
  margin-left: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Example 1 Example 1 Example 1 Example 1 Example 1 Example 1 Example 1 Example 1 Example 1</li>
  <li>Example 2</li>
  <li>Example 3</li>
  <li>Example 4</li>
  <li>Example 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot :)

Comment: Just quick follow up, how to I make the whole content get tabbed if it spans across multiple lines?

Comment: @BarryDoyle I edited my answer. I've added a left margin to `li`s and the same but negative left margin to the counter.

Comment: Perfect! Thank so much :)